# Find my App name in iTunes connect

Tags: app-store-connect

Finally, Apple posted my app in the AppStore!

Now, I want to link to it, and for that I need to find the app name which is used in the link:

http://itunes.com/apps/appname

The name I thought was right, which appears when I use "View in App Store" on iTunes Connect that directs me to: 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appname/idappid?ls=1&mt=8

just does not seem to work… the link does not open on the iPhone. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to one of my apps

https://itunes.apple.com/se/app/medicinsk-ordbok/id425404620?mt=8

[Medicinsk ordbok](https://itunes.apple.com/se/app/medicinsk-ordbok/id425404620?mt=8)

Hence, try to remove "ls=1&"